# Popup sporadically flickers when setting margin (after animation)

Tags: wpf, animation, popup, dropdown

I'm creating a drop-down button which consists of a `ToggleButton` and a `ContextMenu`. The menu opens when the button is clicked and is aligned with the button using a `CustomPopupPlacementCallback`.

I apply a customized animation to the menu when it opens, like this:

```cs
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenu contextMenu = (ContextMenu)sender;

    NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());

    TranslateTransform translation = new TranslateTransform();
    RegisterName("TranslateTransform", translation);

    contextMenu.RenderTransform = translation;

    DoubleAnimation translationAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        From = -20,
        To = 0,
        Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)),
        EasingFunction = new PowerEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut, Power = 3 }
    };

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translationAnimation, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(translationAnimation, "TranslateTransform");

    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(translationAnimation);

    storyboard.Begin(this);
}
```

This works fine and makes the menu appear to "slide out of the button":

[image: Dropdown animation as intended but without dropshadow]

**Side notes:**

- I'm using a custom animation because the default `PopupAnimation.Slide` doesn't meet my needs in terms of timing
- I'm aware that I could also animate the `ContextMenu.VerticalOffsetProperty`, but this would make the menu overlap the button during the animation. Animating the `RenderTransform`, on the other hand, seems to be doing what I want.

Now I have added a dropshadow to the menu, which requires the `ContextMenu` to have a margin (otherwise the dropshadow would be clipped). This kind of breaks the alignment of the menu because it now overlaps the button during the animation (which I wanted to avoid in the first place):

[image: Menu with dropshadow overlapping the button]

So I've come up with the idea of removing the top margin from the menu during the animation and restoring it afterwards, like this:

```cs
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thickness originalMargin = contextMenu.Margin;
    contextMenu.Margin = new Thickness(
        contextMenu.Margin.Left, 0, contextMenu.Margin.Right, contextMenu.Margin.Bottom);

    /* Prepare animation as shown before... */

    storyboard.Completed += new EventHandler((animation, eventArgs) =>
    {
        contextMenu.Margin = originalMargin; 
    });

    storyboard.Begin(this);
}
```

This works as intended most of the time - the popup is aligned perfectly during the animation and the dropshadow becomes visible at the top after the animation has finished. However, when the margin is being restored, the popup sometimes moves out of place very briefly:

[image: Menu with shadow, moving out of place sporadically]

I'm aware that changing the `Margin` property of the `ContextMenu` will cause the layout system to re-evaluate the placement of the popup. But I don't know why sometimes there is this intermediate frame before the placement is updated. Also, I don't quite understand why the popup jumps upwards when the top margin is actually being increased.

**Update:** Ironically, on slower machines, the behavior is observed significantly less frequent...

Is there anything I can do about this issue?

As always, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I would like to try it, but I think I will require the styles and xaml for the ToggleButton. Can you post the code for reproduce this or can you upload your code in a repository like guthub?

Comment: I will try to extract the files of interest and upload them to GitHub...

Comment: I have uploaded a Visual Studio solution to https://github.com/MisterNobody123/DropDownButtonDemo

Comment: I just noticed that in DropDownButton.xaml, the offset of the ContextMenu is bound to its own margin (inverted, so that it aligns with the button). I think this might be an issue...

Comment: Thanks @mister.nobody. The issue that you comment, if you found the solution, write a answer for your question

Comment: I was wrong. It seems to me like when I modify the margin or offset properties, the popup is sometimes redrawn before the positioning is re-evaluated by the layout system...

Comment: for the comment that you did it before, you found the solution for your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I can't find a way to reliably control when the popup position is updated. No matter what I do, there's always this small chance that the popup will flicker sooner or later...

Comment: I found that removing the verticaloffset in the DropDownButton.xaml, the ContextMenu doesn't bounce. Maybe the bouncy effect is related to that.

Comment: Comment the line //contextMenu.Margin = originalMargin; in the Completed event of the storyboard. Add inside VerticalOffsetcontextMenu.VerticalOffset = 0.4; (I can't push the changes since I don't have permissions on your github repository)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you avoid restoring the margin after the animation has finished. This will, however, permanently remove the dropshadow from the top of the menu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured out a workaround.

I'm leaving the `Margin` property untouched throughout the entire process. This avoids the original problem but, as shown before, makes the menu overlap the button (see second animation in my original question).

Now I have to compensate for the unwanted offset, but I can't use the `VerticalOffset` property (because removing it after the animation has finished will again result in sporadic flicker). Instead, I use a clipping geometry and animate it so that it always clips the part of the menu which overlaps the button:

```
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /* Prepare translation animation as shown before... */

    RectangleGeometry clipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(
        new Point(-contextMenu.Margin.Left, 0),
        new Size(contextMenu.ActualWidth + contextMenu.Margin.Left + contextMenu.Margin.Right,
            contextMenu.ActualHeight + contextMenu.Margin.Bottom)));
    contextMenu.RegisterName("RectangleGeometry", clipGeometry);

    contextMenu.Clip = clipGeometry;

    RectAnimation clippingAnimation = new RectAnimation()
    {
        Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 200)),
        EasingFunction = new PowerEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut, Power = 3 },
        From = new Rect(
            new Point(-contextMenu.Margin.Left, 20),
            new Size(contextMenu.ActualWidth + contextMenu.Margin.Left + contextMenu.Margin.Right,
                contextMenu.ActualHeight - 20 + contextMenu.Margin.Bottom))
    };

    SetTargetProperty(clippingAnimation, new PropertyPath(RectangleGeometry.RectProperty));
    SetTargetName(clippingAnimation, "RectangleGeometry");

    storyboard.Children.Add(clippingAnimation);

    storyboard.Completed += new EventHandler((animation, eventArgs) =>
    {
        contextMenu.RenderTransform = null;
        contextMenu.Clip = null; 
    });

    storyboard.Begin(this);
}
```